# How to make a grid same as a bootstrap in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I make a grid on ionic framework but its not work same as a bootstrap grid like as a responsive. So I want to same grid as a bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33" ng-click="goProfile()"> 
        <div class="box"></div> 
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="col col-33" ng-click="gotoExtProfile()"> 
    <div class="box"></div> 
    <div class="box-title"><a href="">Extended Profile</a></div>
 </div> 
<div class="col col-33" ng-click="gotoMspAgreements()"> 
    <div class="box"></div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you can add your code, so we can see what you have tried so far.

Comment: I use col col-33. In ionic all sizes use col-33. I want small sizes to decrease this size.

Comment: You need to add the code to your question. It helps if you add enough code to see what you are doing.

Comment: <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-33" ng-click="goProfile()">
                <div class="box">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-33" ng-click="gotoExtProfile()">
                <div class="box" >
                </div>
                <div class="box-title"><a href="">Extended Profile</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="col col-33" ng-click="gotoMspAgreements()">
                <div class="box">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

Comment: I added this into the question, my edit is pending approval. You have too many closing div tags. Is there code missing?

Comment: You are using Ionic, not Bootstrap, so if you want a Bootstrap grid, why not add the Bootstrap grid to your code?

Comment: I want a ionic framework. so I can't use bootstrap. because class is comflict

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how Ionic grid works

> By default every col added inside a row will automatically receive an
>   equal amount of the available area.......
>   ..... each of the five columns in this example will each evenly take up 20% of the available width (thank you flexbox).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
  <div class="col">.col</div>
</div>
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even